# Reducing the number of words in a sentence

Tags: grammar, sentence

Is it possible to reduce the word count of the following sentence, and if so, what would be the resulting sentence?:

> I eat lunch and then sometimes have desert; and, sometimes for desert, I will eat spinach.

Comment: Please explain why you want fewer words.

Comment: Exactly how much of the original wording and meaning needs to be kept? Which parts of the sentence need to be reduced? For instance *I eat lunch and then sometimes* does not mean exactly the same thing as *after lunch I sometimes* or *with lunch I sometimes*. If the meaning needs to be precise, then *I eat lunch and then sometimes* cannot be reduced. (However, everything after the semicolon can be reduced.)

Comment: I think you have strayed on the wrong site. This site is concerned with questions about the English Language. It is not a service for copy fiitters or people wishing to learn to express themselves more succinctly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
*The odd spinach figures as my occasional lunch dessert.*

Comment: Can 'spinach' be used in a count way like this?